# .mov playing the sound but no video

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, media-player

I'am playing a .mov file from VTC but the thing is each time I run the video on VLC player. the .mov is working there is an audio but video seems to be stuck in one place. how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vlc player not playing the video content](http://superuser.com/questions/85260/vlc-player-not-playing-the-video-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Quicktime player. You can download it at http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/.

You might also have a look at this answer: https://superuser.com/a/68541/127982

Answer (score 0):

Try updating or reinstalling VLC to get the latest codecs. Sometimes that playback result is due to missing codecs.